# Django Private Channel - if self.object. #(consumer: One or the other: seller# != request.user:

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a channel. I don't want the other users have an access to the detail views. The thing is I can make it accessible to one but I don't know how to make it accessible for both consumer & seller?

```
class Group(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="", blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="")
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#Detail channel
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/cooker/login'),name="dispatch")
class CheckoutDetail(generic.DetailView):
    ...
    
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.consumer or self.object.seller != request.user: #it's redirect me to home page
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')    
        
        return super(CheckoutDetail, self).get(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct logic would be

```
if not (request.user == self.object.consumer or request.user == self.object.seller):
    return redirect(...)
```

but I'd refactor that logic into a function in the `object`, e.g.

```
def has_access(self, user):
    return (self.consumer == user or self.seller == user)
```

and then call it, e.g.

```
if not self.object.has_access(user=request.user):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you :) you understood perfectly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, you must change this line like this:

```
    if self.object.consumer != request.user and self.object.seller != request.user:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: sorry I did not make myself clear. Assume I'm a consumer and I'm creating a channel with one user (like x), a seller. I want x and me to have access to this channel.

Comment: with your code as I'm consumer I can not have access to it :) it should be One or the other

Comment: No problem :) I am stuck to misunderstand you more now :) Sorry for my bad English maybe i cant understand point of problem :( are you want if correct everything, you dont want return HttpResponseRedirect('/') ? this is true ?